# How to do hybrid client- and server-side pagination with datatables, such that first X rows are client-paginated?

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'd like to avoid doing many smaller queries, and do one query that grabs 1000 rows from the server, and paginate them with 50 on each page. How do I make it so that page 21 will render a new query to get the next 20 pages?

This also means that ordering columns will require new server-side requests, as well.

Comment: This sounds like an awesome feature. I can only offer a hunch but I would think you would first alter the iTotalRecords value to represent everything in your db. Then create or utilize a paging plugin that would keep know when to go back to the server. I don't think I've come across an implementation of datatables that can seamlessly switch between client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to cache certain number of pages while working with jQuery DataTables in server-side processing mode, see [Pipelining data to reduce Ajax calls for paging](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html).

From the [description](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html):

> This example shows one technique to reduce the number of Ajax calls that are made to the server by caching more data than is needed for each draw. This is done by intercepting the Ajax call and routing it through a data cache control; using the data from the cache if available, and making the Ajax request if not.

There are configuration options that allow you to configure how many pages can be retrieved at once, see `pages` property:

```js
// Configuration options
var conf = $.extend( {
    pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
    url: '',      // script url
    data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                  // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
    method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
}, opts );
```